# Newline is not like how i expected

Tags: javascript, newline

I am writing these sentences to my VS code

```js
var myStr = "FirstLine\nSecondLine\nThirdLine";
console.log(myStr);
```

But the result is not same with what i expected.

I expected

```
FirstLine
SecondLine
ThirdLine
```

But the result in the HTML console is

```
FirstLine
    \SecondLine
ThirdLine
```

Comment: This works fine for me. What browser are you using?

Comment: @MichaelM. Google Chrome. If its perfect code, there is no problem. I thought there is an issue about code.

Answer (score -1):

if youre using a linux based machine
try to set

```
  "files.insertFinalNewline": false,
  "files.eol" : '\n'
```

in VScode settings

if it is so try

```
console.log("FirstLine" + "\n" + "SecondLine" + "\n" + "ThirdLine");
```